# Метод деления отрезка пополам

Tags: c++, c, численные-методы, числа-с-плавающей-точкой

В правильно написанной программе число вычислений функции отличается от числа итераций метода на 2. Как исправить программу, чтобы программа правильно работала?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int sign(double x);
double shaq(double x);
double my_exp(double x);
int root_half(double a, double b, double (*f)(double), double eps)
{
    double c; int chislo=0,funci=0;
    if (sign(f(a))==sign(f(b))) {printf("Метод не применим\n");return 0;}
    do
    {
        c=(a+b)/2.0;
        if(sign(f(c))==0){funci++; printf("Корень: %lf\n",c);break;}
        else
        if(sign(f(a))==sign(f(c))){printf("Корень: %lf\n",c);a=c;funci+=2;}
        else 
        {printf("Корень: %lf\n",c);b=c;}
        chislo++;
        }
while ( fabs(b-a)>=eps);
printf("Количество итераций: %d\n Количество Вычислений функций:%d\n",chislo,funci);
return 0;
}

int sign(double x){
   if(x>0)return 1;
   else
   if(x<0)return -1;
   else if(x==0)return 0;
   return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
   double a,b,f(double),eps=0.01;
   scanf("%le %lf",&a,&b);
   root_half(a,b,&f,eps);
   return 0;
}

double f( double x)
{
    return x*x*x -2*x*x+3;
}
```

Comment: А зачем вы вычисляете на каждой итерации такое количество раз все функции? Это вы еще подвираете; поставьте счетчик **в самой функции** и будете удивлены... Посмотрите тут - https://ideone.com/OzTjyk - сколько раз вы ее **на самом деле** вычисляете.

Comment: А Как исправить ?

Comment: Ну вот почему стандартное - почему у меня ошибка? Объясняешь. Тут же - а как мне написать правильно? А **подумать**? Ну вот я написал за вас - вы что, чему-то научились?... увы.

Comment: Все я понял) Спасибо большое

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я бы делал так:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int funci;

double f( double x)
{
    ++funci;
    return x*x*x -2*x*x+3;
}

double root_half(double a, double b, double (*f)(double), double eps)
{
    double c; int chislo = 1;

    double fa = f(a), fb = f(b);

    if (fa*fb > 0) { printf("Метод неприменим\n"); return 0; }

    for(;fabs(b-a)>=eps; chislo++)
    {
        c=(a+b)/2.0;
        double fc = f(c);
        if (fc == 0)
        {
            printf("Количество итераций: %d\n",chislo);
            return c;
        }

        if (fc*fa > 0) { a = c; } else { b = c; }
    }

    printf("Количество итераций: %d\n",chislo);
    return c;
}

int main(void)
{
    double a,b;
    scanf("%lf %lf",&a,&b);
    printf("Корень = %lf\n",root_half(a,b,f,1e-5));

    printf("Вызовов функций: %d\n",funci);

}
```

Comment: Здравствуйте. А вы можете дописать программу, пожалуйста, используя функцию сигнум? Я пишу учителю не нравится )

Comment: Ну напишите сами, в чем проблема? У меня проверка одинаковости знаков `x` и `y` имеет вид `if (x*y > 0)` - перепишите ее через `sign`, что сложного?

Comment: Да пишу я , учитель что то говорит постоянно,пишет , что в программе ошибки.

Comment: Разжевываю до полной невкусности: замените все `fc*fa > 0` на `sign(fc) == sign(fa)`.

Comment: Спасибо, но я уже сам разобрался!